# Why is line solid?

Tags: gnuplot

I type in gnuplot "plot cos(x) lt 2" and want to take dashed line, but I take only solid line.
I use gnuplot 4.2 and ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Terminal being used via

`set term TYPE_OF_TERMINAL OPTIONS`

Some Terminals are unable to display dashed lines.
You would see Terminal being set at the start: `Terminal type set to 'TYPE_OF_TERMINAL'`

example for ps/eps : `set term postscript eps enhanced`
At least this way you can include it in your TeX documents.

Comment: gnuplot could draw dashed line with these option, but it couldn`t draw any others(jpeg, png)

Comment: @mystdeim because they are not available. The options available are listed right after you set term. You can try opening the eps in GhostView/one of image editing tools or use GhostScript/some other command line tool to convert it